# PHP page numbering not displaying previous page numbers correctly

Tags: php

I am using this code to display previous page numbers and page number in between.

if `current_page = 2` then it shows the following page numbers:

```
1 1 2 3 4 5 6...
```

and the same if `current_page = 10`, it will show:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 6 7 8 9... etc

$range = 4;
for($i = $current_page - $range; $i < ($current_page + $range) + 1; $i++) {
                if($i > 0 && $i <= $total_pages) {
                    if($i == $current_page) {
                        //$button_display.= ' [<strong>'.$i.'</strong>] ';
                        $button_display.= ' <input type="button" value="'.$i.'" class="active" /> ';
                    } else {
                        $button_display.= ' <input type="button" onClick="parent.location=\'?page='.$i.'\'" value="'.$i.'" /> '; 
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I don't see a problem unless you're setting $button_display somewhere before this - I notice that you're only ever appending to it. What do you initialise it to?

Comment: i use $button_display for all the numbered buttons and the next/previous buttons then just echo it at the end

Comment: OK, but that doesn't answer my question. Perhaps you could include the code where you initialise $button_display.

Comment: Your code works fine for me.